# Could not create SSL/TLS Secure Channel

Tags: javascript, facebook, httpwebrequest, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm only *sometimes* getting this error - it seems like it only happens sometimes. If I refresh the page, it seems to fix itself. Any ideas?

```
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

From this code:

```
    string ThirdURL = "https://api.facebook.com/method/users.getInfo?uids=" + FacebookUserID + "&client_id=" + AppCode.Facebook.APPLICATION_ID + "&access_token=" + AccessToken + "&fields=first_name,last_name,current_location,email,birthday,sex,pic_square,locale&format=json";
    HttpWebRequest APIThirdRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ThirdURL);
    StreamReader APIThirdResponse = new StreamReader(APIThirdRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());

//error on line below -->
        string MoreAPIData = APIThirdResponse.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: We're seeing the same error occasionally for the past few weeks. There  was a fb bug ticket about it recently. http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/367369176650486

Comment: We are seeing this error increasingly during past few days. Anyone has the solution for the problem?

Comment: we found our issue to be our webhost, they included the ip address of graph.facebook.com to the host file in our accounts and all was well.

resolved to be an ipv6 issue.

Comment: This is not webhost issue, this is issue with Facebook API - http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/318333734927578

Comment: Currently-open bug report in https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/335732253172491

Comment: We ended up doing a try catch loop for now.

Answer (score 1):

This was a temporary issue from Facebook's side. While it lasted an solution was to do a "try-catch loop" with x amount of max retries of the request, even if it might be considered bad practice.

The issue itself is resolved since 2012-07-17.

Tickets on Facebook Developers about the issue:

- [The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/397592836945114)
- [Intermitent SSL certificate errors: "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/335732253172491)